# Can I prevent some iPhone apps from needing to be reloaded?

Tags: iphone, ios

Recently some iPhone apps which are already installed are not available when clicked.

I noticed recently some apps I don’t use often need to be reloaded. I assume this is some kind of memory reallocation innovation to make room for all of my favorite podcasts.

It happens like this, I click on an icon, and a clock-like loading animation covers the icon and it’s unavailable until it’s “reloaded”. Ok. But this necessitates WiFi, and near impossible to reload while on the train, for example.

Today I was not able to use my gmail app, and more importantly Transit app were unavailable when I needed them. I absolutely can’t have Transit app ever unavailable or requiring download  as I rely it to find alternate routes home during my NYC commute to work and home.

Is there a way to prevent certain critical third-party apps from unloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apps are being **offloaded**. You can easily turn this off by going to settings > iTunes & App Store > Offload Unused Apps.
[image]

Comment: so it's all or nothing? I use Gmail and Transit every day (or at least every other day). So, I'm just not using my _iPhone_ enough for the algorith to recognize what's 'unused'? Wow.

Comment: @xtian Unfortunately, yes